# Swinject - Ambiguous reference to member

Tags: swift, dependency-injection, swinject

I am using [Swinject](https://github.com/Swinject/Swinject) in my `Swift 3` app. When I tried

```
let container = Container()
container.register(NetworkModeling.self) { _ in Network() }
```

I get an error saying

```
Ambiguous reference to member 'register(_:name:factory:)'
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Doesn't the compiler also give you a list of possible overloads?

Comment: The swinject documentation demonstrate she the same

Comment: How did you install Swinject, eg. Carthage or CocoaPods? Which code in the documentation demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Could I please direct your attention to this similar question, thank you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40002322/swinject-service-class-without-parameters-failing-to-register-in-container-scop

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I faced the same issue and i think compiler could be a bit more verbose in this case.

Anyway, my problem was on my side, not in [Swinject](https://github.com/Swinject/Swinject)

Check the following:

1. `NetworkModeling` and `Network` are visible in scope of your registration (they are `public`, or `internal` in the same module. remember, that swift3 introduced `fileprivate` and many other specifiers, so make sure your identifiers are visible to registeting code
2. Make sure that `Network` conforms to `NetworkModeling`. Being unable to see inheritance, swift compiler raises error about ambigous types for Swinject factory

Hope, this helps

Comment: #2 above was extremely helpful