# Swinject service class without parameters failing to register in .container scope with Swift 3.0: why?

Tags: swift, swinject

I've created a super simple protocol:

```
protocol IndependentProtocol {}
```

and service:

```
class IndependentService: IndependentProtocol {}
```

and the following `Swinject` registration works:

```
defaultContainer.register( IndependentProtocol.self )
{ 
    _ in IndependentService()
}
```

but the following one does not:

```
defaultContainer.register( IndependentProtocol.self )
{ 
    _ in IndependentService()
}.inObjectScope( .Container )
```

error given is:

```
Ambiguous reference to member 'register(_:name:factory:)'
```

and interestingly, the following works (ie: services with parameters *can be registered* in `.container` scope):

```
    defaultContainer.register( AnotherProtocol.self )
    {
        r in AnotherService(
            signals: r.resolve( AnotherService.self )!
        )
    }.inObjectScope( .container )
```

I have read this similar question, which did not help: [Swinject - Ambiguous reference to member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39813830/swinject-ambiguous-reference-to-member)

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Problem is probably in capitalized `.Container` - swift 3 version uses `case` names with lowercase first letter.

Comment: Feel like Homer: "d'oh!" Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Jakub has commented, the issue lies with your capitalization of `.Container`. Update the registration to the following:

```
defaultContainer.register(IndependentProtocol.self, factory: { _ in 
    IndependentService()
}).inObjectScope(.container)
```